# Which element to use in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find "Moderat" in `<p class="text-spread-level">Moderat</p>`

I have tried with `id`, `name`, `xpath` and `link text`.

Comment: Please post the code that you tried and explain what was the issue when you tried it.

Comment: Which programming language you are using ? How did you try with xpath ? Was there any error ?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.text-spread-level')
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mybars"]/div/p)
driver.find_element_by_name('Moderat').

These are some of them, nothing special happens. I run the code with no faults. How do I know it fetched the right element? And how do I print it as i want?

This is a pollen spread warning site in Norway, i want to "print" the spread in my program into (translated to English) No spread, Decent Spread, High Spread etc... 

I would like to print "1" IF no spread, if that makes sense.

Comment: To get the text just use the `text` attribute `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.text-spread-level').text`

Comment: I am using Python, pycharm as ide, selenium, geocoder. Hope this answers your question.
This is my first beginner project so i found some of the selenium tuts on youtube and they were fairly understandable.

Comment: The code and other relevant data should be edited to the question, you can use the `Edit` button under the post to do that and add `python` tag next to `selenium` tag to mention the language.

Comment: Done, thanks. When running the code "driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.text-spread-level').Moderat" im getting : AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Moderat'

Comment: Not `.Moderat`, use `.text`. This will return `'Moderat'`.

Comment: Ahhhh, awesome! I was sure I had to rewrite that "text" myself. Haha. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to try this?

```py
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests

  sentences = []
  res = requests.get(url) # assign your url in variable
  soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
  tag_list = soup.select("p.text-spread-level")
  for tag in tag_list:
    sentences.append(tag.text)
  print(sentences)
```

Comment: Thank you! Im trying to do this with Selenium, maybe i'll try beautiful soup at a later stage, but right now im trying to get the hang on Selenium. Do you know how to do it in Selenium?

Comment: does this work?

restext = driver.find_element_by_class_name("text-spread-level").text

print(restext)

if you not add "text", you will get <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement...>

Answer (score 0):

Find the element by class name and get the text.

```
el=driver.find_element_by_class_name('text-spread-level')
val=el.text
print(val)
```

Comment: if it helps you pls accept it as correct answer and upvote it

Comment: I need more rep to vote, im sorry. Gave the correct answer to the other guy who was first because hes answers also helped me.